# delegate UITableView presentation to another class

Tags: ios, delegates, uitableview

I have a ViewController with a nib file and want to delegate code that will affect how a UITableView is presented to another class. Why is a long story, but it involves a collaborator inheriting from another class which overrides the cellForRowAtIndexPath method amongst others.

I am using the following code in my main ViewController:

```
tableDelegate = [[TableDelegate alloc] init];
tableView.delegate = tableDelegate;
[tableView setNeedsDisplay];
```

TableDelegate is defined as:

```
@interface MessCenTableController : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
NSArray *dataSourceArray; }
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSArray *dataSourceArray;
```

I then init the tableDelegate with the datasource object.

The IBOutlet is set to the tableView, but the TableViewDelegate methods are not being called.

Do I have to do something in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the tableview datasource as well

```
tableView.dataSource = tableDelegate
```

Comment: Thanks - apologies for such an obvious question!